Fallback way to publish item when Sitecore Publishing Service is down
We have configured the Sitecore publishing service for our application. We want to implement a fallback way to publish items when SPS is down.
Is there any way, we can publish the item when SPS is down?
We don't want to revert to the SPS module, instead, we want a fallback option when SPS is down.
For example, we can move items with the highest priority to web db with the transfer option, but we can't move related items with that.
is there any we can move related items with transfer options?

Sitecore Publishing Service (SPS) supports horizontal scaling, so you can have multiple instances of the Publishing Service connected to your Sitecore instance if you need to make it more resilient.
As SPS does not allow parallel publishing by multiple servers, the horizontal scaling caters exclusively for high availability and automatic failover scenarios, not for increasing the throughput of publishing operations.

When multiple Publishing Service instances are running, all of them
can receive web-API calls. However, only one instance will have the
job system active and therefore perform the actual publishing jobs. If
the active instance fails, another instance will become active. This
happens automatically because of a heartbeat protocol that is
implemented via the service database.

If you would like to configure SPS for high availability and automatic failover, please refer to the section "High Availability Configuration of the Sitecore Publishing Service" in the PDF document "Sitecore Publishing Service
Installation and Configuration Guide". You can download this document for your version of SPS from the website https://developers.sitecore.com/downloads/Sitecore_Publishing_Service.

Using the Sitecore Publishing Service (SPS) module, users can revert to the default publishing process with few configuration changes.

For Sitecore XP 10.1 and earlier versions:

Locate the Sitecore.Publishing.Service.*.config files and change the file extension to .disabled. The files can be found in the following folders:

Sitecore XP 8.2: the /App_Config/Include folder.
Sitecore XP 9.0: the /App_Config/Modules/PublishingService folder.


Switch to the Core database and rename the /sitecore/system/Aliases/Applications/Publish item to PublishDisabled.


For Sitecore XP 10.2 and later versions:

Disable Sitecore.Publishing.Service.*.config files in /App_Config/Modules/PublishingService folder
Remove Sitecore.Publishing.Service.*.dll from /bin folder
Remove items.core.sps.dat from /sitecore modules/items/core folder.



Read more details: Revert to default publishing after installing the Sitecore Publishing Service module 
Hope it helps!

We don't want to revert to the SPS module, instead, we want a fallback option when SPS is down. For example, we can move items with the highest priority to web db with the transfer option, but we can't move related items with that.

In case of SPS down, You need to fix an issue related to SPS. There is no such fallback option.
